# Proof of Inverse of Cosine Transforms

Tags: calculus, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Inverses of Cosine Theorem:

For $$F_c(\omega) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) \cos (\omega t) dt,$$ $$f(t)=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} F_c(\omega)\cos (\omega t) d\omega .$$

I want proof of this theorem, but I can't find it in textbooks.

I want to seek a hint for this proof.

What I tried is:

$$F_c(\omega) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)\cos (\omega t) dt$$
\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty} F_c (\omega) \cos (\omega t) d\omega &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos \omega t \left(\int_0^{\infty} f(t) \cos (\omega t) dt \right) d \omega \\&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos (\omega t) d \omega \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) \cos (\omega t) dt\\
\end{align} but I don't know how to do further steps.

Edit 1:
Inverses of Cosine Theorem:

For $$F_c(\omega) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) \cos (\omega t) dt,$$ $$f(\tau)=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} F_c(\omega)\cos (\omega \tau) d\omega .$$
My Approach:
$$F_c(\omega) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)\cos (\omega t) dt$$
\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty} F_c (\omega) \cos (\omega \tau) d\omega &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos \omega \tau \left(\int_0^{\infty} f(t) \cos (\omega t) dt \right) d \omega \\&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos (\omega \tau) d \omega \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) \cos (\omega t) d\tau\\
\end{align} but I don't know how to do further steps.

Edit 2:

Textbook Used: P.P.G. Dyke, "An Introduction to Laplace Transforms and Fourier Series", Springer (P. 135)

Comment: I edited in $F_c(\omega)$ in the second integral, because I assumed it was a mistake to leave it out. I have not seen cosine transforms before though, so do correct this if it is wrong

Comment: One small comment, when you replace $F_c(\omega)$ by it's integral definition, you shouldn't call the integration variable $t$ since that is an independent variable. Try using $s$ or $t'$ or $\tau$ (these are common choices but anything works).

Comment: What are the assumptions for the "theorem"?

Comment: @podiki I hope that my correction on edit 1 is correct (although the textbook really just use the same variable for $t$)

Comment: @LouisPan There is no any condition stated in the theorem in the textbook. It just mentions the formula directly. I have attached the name of book into Edit 2.

Comment: @FShrike Yes, your correction is right. Sorry that I missed the important $F_c(\omega)$